# Fixed-size imageView in UITableViewCell or fixed text positioning?

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uiimageview, size

Is there any known way to resize the imageView of a `UITableViewCell` to a fixed size, so the text on the right is always aligned?

Alternatively, I'd position the textLabels to a fixed position with a fixed width.

However, setting center, frame or bounds on both the labels and the imageView results in nothing.

Does anyone has the code handy how to create a transparent `UIImage` (well, or `CGImage`) and copy my image in the center of it, without any scaling applied?

Answer (score 1):

Subclass UITableViewCell and override -layoutSubviews.

Answer (score 0):

If the built in label and image view aren't to your liking, you can create your own and add them as subviews.

Comment: It's not so much that the built-in image view "aren't to liking"; it's that it doesn't work at all like any other UIImageView in that it doesn't respond to resizing, content mode, etc. Very annoying.